# Nextjs tailwind Warning: Prop `className` did not match

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have getting the following warning, I am unsure of how to get it to go away:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. 

 Server: "flex items-center justify-start my-2 p-4 text-sm w-full hover:text-white rounded-r-lg \n       

 font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 rounded-r-lg group flex items-center px-2 py-2" 

 Client: "flex items-center justify-start my-2 p-4 text-sm w-full hover:text-white rounded-r-lg \n            
 text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-700 group flex items-center px-2 py-2"
 a

_c<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:133:27
```

The area where it is in my code is:

```
const style = {
  inactive: `text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-700`,
  active: `font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 rounded-r-lg`,
  link: `flex items-center justify-start my-2 p-4 text-sm w-full hover:text-white rounded-r-lg`,
};

 function Items() {
   const { asPath } = useRouter();
   return (
     <ul>
      <li>
         {data.map((item) => (
           <Link href={item.link} key={item.title}>
            <a
               className={classNames(
                 `${style.link} 
                  ${item.link === asPath ? style.active : style.inactive}`,
            "group flex items-center px-2 py-2"
          )}
        >
```

EDIT: added more code

Comment: `className={classNames('${style.link}` Where does "classNames" come from? Try `className={style.link}`

Comment: added more info. I think the issue might be about the asPath where it checks if the current nav item is active or not. Not sure why it is giving the warning however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `classNames` here

Below is the code , please check

```
const style = {
  inactive: `text-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-700`,
  active: `font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 rounded-r-lg`,
  link: `flex items-center justify-start my-2 p-4 text-sm w-full hover:text-white rounded-r-lg`,
};

 function Items() {
   const { asPath } = useRouter();
   return (
     <ul>
      <li>
         {data.map((item) => (
           <Link href={item.link} key={item.title}>
            <a
               className={
                 `${style.link} 
                  ${item.link === asPath ? style.active : style.inactive}
            group flex items-center px-2 py-2`
          )}
        >
```

Comment: Why he needs to remove the `classNames` function?